# save function for arraylists and objects?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, save

I have been trying to make an application that will work like a mission log for a space crew for some time now. I have all of the basics worked out. The entire thing works by adding custom objects with properties entered by the user to Array lists. The Objects then have ArrayLists inside of them for further Object Storing.

Any help is appreciated, I am mostly self taught and am trying to learn coding to the best of my ability.

the link for the GitHub with the src folder and the .jar export is below

[GitHub For the Code](https://github.com/MikeLeoni/Java-Crew-Log-System)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You need to expand your question because it's so vast for help.

Comment: What was the question, again? I would suggest you isolate the specific problem you are having - and present it here ... otherwise if you expect people to read trough your entire github..and come up with some suggestions  - I am afraid you will be disappointed....

Comment: Don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post.